# Triggering a script to run based on a value changed automatically by a formula

Tags: javascript, java, triggers, onchange

I am working on a project in Google Sheets for my job in which I need to edit a script that is supposed to send an automated email whenever a value is changed in either of two specific columns. The issue is that these columns' values change based on a lookup table pointing to another speadsheet, which also changes automatically based on some other schedule that I am not allowed access to.

The onEdit trigger doesn't work because it relies on a manual entry by a user. I have tried the onChange trigger but I'm not entirely clear on what exactly it does. The best I could find explaining it just says "specifies a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed". My online searching has turned up suggestions to make a time based trigger that checks the current value against a base value every 5 minutes or so and if the current value is different from the base value it sends the email and updates the base value to match the current value, but that seems really complicated.

I am almost entirely self taught in this, and feel that I am quickly getting out of my depth. Assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert on Google Sheets, but a bit of a play there is a trigger called `from spreadsheet / on change` I would use that.  Store you previous value inside a another cell, if the current cell is different to the newly changed cell, you could then send the email & update the other cell to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit more playing with Google Sheets..

As a simple example of detecting changes to a Cell, I've created a really simple script, attach this script to the `From Spreadshet / On Change` trigger.

If you change cell `A1`, it will pop up a Toast to show it changed, of course in your version you will send an email instead & the cells references will be different,  cell `A2` is used to track the last value.

Hope this helps..

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var a1 = a.getRange("a1");
  var a2 = a.getRange("a2");
  if (a1.getValue() !== a2.getValue()) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Cell A1 changed", "changed");
    a2.setValue(a1.getValue());
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Work picked up some so I haven't had a chance to make much progress on this pet project, but that definitely seems like it will help me get unstuck and move forward with what I want to do. There were similar issues with a related but slightly different pet project so this looks like it will probably be a good fix to both situations! Thanks again!